# Importing SVG files - font-awesome with Webpack

Tags: svg, webpack, font-awesome

I have a project with webpack which uses svg. Certain inline svg files are translated correctly but those from font-awesome are not.

I import font awesome with:

```
import 'font-awesome-webpack';
```

On the webpack side I have:

```
{
    test: /\.svg$/,
    loaders: [
        'babel-loader',
        {
            loader: 'react-svg-loader',
            query: {
                jsx: true,
            },
        },
    ],
}],
```

This works fine but displays a square instead of font-awesome icons. Now following other fixes I should add a loader config for other non-inline SVGs, such as:

```
{ 
    test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
    loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" 
},
{ 
    test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
    loader: "file-loader"
}
```

As soon as I add the above lines and attempt to launch my project the following error is displayed:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid tag:/f01bf49c263128347d1c47cdc55eff66.svg
```

The issue comes clearly from the way I load Svgs following my wbepack config, but regardless of the different ways I import my svgs, the same error continues to break my project.

Is it possible that the two webpack config create a conflict?
What am I doing wrong with my webpack config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI solution is:

webpack config file:

```
 {
  test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
  loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff',
}, {
  test: /\.(ttf|otf|eot|svg)(\?v=[a-z0-9]\.[a-z0-9]\.[a-z0-9])?$/,
  use: [{
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      outputPath: 'fonts',
      publicPath: 'fonts',
    },
  }],
},
```